# can calling clone() from static method?

Tags: java

Given the caveat, a non-static method can't be called from a static method, how can the object of `yoyo` be cloned?

```
class yoyo{
    int x,y;
    yoyo(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();   
    }
}

class test {
    public static void main(String str[]) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        yoyo y = new yoyo(1,2);
        yoyo y1 = (yoyo)yoyo.clone();
        System.out.println(y1.x+"  "+y1.y);
    }
};
```

Comment: WHat's the problem with your code ?

Comment: It looks like you want to do `(yoyo)y.clone()`

Comment: The question has been edited for clarification.

Comment: Hint: `clone` is an instance method and it means "clone *this* object".  So you have to call it on an instance.

Comment: Sorry this i a Wrong Question .. i did a big mistake .. i am calling the non-static member function using the class name .. I was drunked that night :D
instead of this -> yoyo y1 = (yoyo)yoyo.clone();
i need to do this -> yoyo y1 = (yoyo)y.clone();
clone() should be called from the instance because we need to pass this instance as this pointer

Answer (score 2):

- The `clone()` method should be called on an instance of a class, not on the class itself
- the class should implement `Cloneable`
- the reason why this method (clone) is not very usued and sometime non-recommended is because you have to implement the logic (and recursivly if needeed) for primitives types, a constructor that takes another instance can be preferred

```
class Yoyo implements Cloneable{
    // ...

    public Yoyo(Yoyo copy){
        this.x = copy.x;
        this.y = copy.y
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone(); 
    }
}

public static void main(String str[]) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Yoyo y = new Yoyo (1,2);
    Yoyo y1 = (Yoyo)y.clone();                  // on y
    System.out.println(y1.x + "  " + y1.y);
}
```

---

*Java convention: class should be name in UpperCamelCase*